# Finding the remainder of a 6 degree polynomial and polynomial itself. Using some algebraic or graphical techniques.

Tags: functions, polynomials

In a six-degree polynomial, say $f(x)$ we have, $$f(1)=1, f(2)=1/2, f(3)=1/3, f(4)=1/4, f(5)=1/5, f(6)=1/6, f(7)=1/7$$ Find $f(8)$ and the polynomial $f(x)$.

This problem comes all the way from the book of an Indian Author. I tried solving the problem using algebra (definitely not by substituting values in the polynomial and solving for SIX variables). According to me, this question is definitely having a more rational approach. I tried using algebraic techniques by manipulating $f(x)$ writing it in terms of a new polynomial say $h(x)$ but in vain. So can anyone of the bright minds out there could help me in attempting the question. It would be a great help.

Comment: Using a computer, I find that $a_6 = \frac{1}{5040}$, $a_5 = -\frac{1}{180}$, $a_4 = \frac{23}{360}$, $a_3 = -\frac{7}{18}$, $a_2 = \frac{80851}{60000}$, $a_1 = -\frac{469}{180}$, and $a_0 = \frac{38893}{15000}$, where $a_n$ is the coefficient of the term $x^n$. These numbers don't look easy to do by hand.

Comment: Is the ans. 1/8?

Comment: @TobyMak. It is funny (may be) but I have different values for $a_2$ and $a_0$. Could you check ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Can someone clarify why the question has been closed as duplicate? The duplicate linked seems to be quite different and I don't see any similarities between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $g(x) = xf(x) - 1$. You have that $g$ is a polynomial of degree 7.
You also know that $$g(n) = nf(n) - 1 = n\cdot1/n - 1= 0,$$ 
for $n = 1, \ldots, 7$. Thus, $g(x)$ factorises as
$$g(x)= A(x - 1)\cdots(x - 7), \quad (*)$$
where $A$ is some real constant.

(We got the above since $g(x)$ is a degree 7 polynomial.)

Now, all we need to do is determine $A$. This is easy because the definition of $g(x)$ tells us that $g(0) = 0f(0) - 1 = -1$. Substituting this in $(*)$ gives us:

$$-1 = A(-1)\cdots(-7) = -5040A$$
$$\implies A = \dfrac{1}{5040}.$$

---

Now, we can retrieve $f(x)$ as $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}(g(x) + 1)$ or

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{5040}(x - 1)\cdots(x - 7) + 1\right).$$

(Note that the constant of the polynomial within the parenthesis is $0$ and thus, $f(x)$ will indeed turn out to be a polynomial.)

---

Calculating $f(8)$ is considerably easier as we get

$$\begin{align}f(8) &= \dfrac{1}{8}\left(\dfrac{1}{5040}(8 - 1)\cdots(8 - 7) + 1\right)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{8}\left(\dfrac{1}{5040}(7)\cdots(1) + 1\right)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{8}(1 + 1) = \boxed{\dfrac{1}{4}}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Aryaman you are life saver again. Thanks for sharing some part of your genius with us.